# Creating Index on a stored procedure used in a Crystal Report SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have never used indexes on a stored procedure so I am seeking help as one of my reports using is running v slow. I have a crystal report which is an aging report. In the procedure itself, it is creating a temp table. The table it is using form temp table has a lot of data and lot of information is being pulled. The end result is the report takes forever to run. Besides creating index on the temp table,any other suggestions are welcome and thanks for looking at this.The  code is as follows.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[ST_Stored] @AsofDate datetime
as
--drop table #rectodate
declare  @rectodate table (transid INT, transrowid INT, reconsum REAL)


INSERT into @rectodate
select      transid, transrowid, sum(reconsum) as reconsum
from  itr1
where reconnum in (select reconnum from oitr where recondate <=@AsofDate)
group by transid, transrowid

select      t0.transid, t2.cardcode,
            case when t0.debit <> 0 then t0.debit - isnull(t1.reconsum,0) else 0 end as OpenDebit,
            case when t0.credit <> 0 then t0.credit - isnull(t1.reconsum, 0) else 0 end as OpenCredit,
            t0.debit, t0.credit,*
            from  jdt1 t0 left outer join @RecToDate t1
            on t0.transid = t1.transid and t0.line_id= t1.transrowid
            left join OINV t2 on t2.CardCode=t0.ShortName
            join oslp on oslp.slpcode = t2.slpcode

where t0.refdate =@AsofDate and t2.slpcode=5
order by t0.transid, t2.cardcode, t0.refdate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The simplest thing you can do is to execute this stored procedure in SSMS with Include Actual Execution Plan option activated to see if SQL Server shows you to create a missing index. If you can then you should publish this execution plan.

2) I would create the following index (if there isn't):

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ INDEX IX_jdt1_refdate_#_transid_lineid_debit_credit
ON dbo.jdt1(refdate)
INCLUDE (transid,line_id,debit,credit)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i will try it. But can I create index on the temp table?

Comment: Yes I tried it, It did not recommend any. There is a clustered index on jdt1 table already.

Comment: If you have a clustered index on `jdt1` then `IX_jdt1_refdate_#_transid_lineid_debit_credit` will be a NONCLUSTERED index.

Comment: So I should just run the sql statement you provided as it is  or it has to be incorporated in the actual procedure? I know it may be a silly question to ask but I don't know much about development so I am asking.

Comment: Yes and you should measure the performance of this stored procedure **before** and **after** index creation with SQL Profiler (SQL:Batch completed event > Duration, CPU and Reads columns > lower values are better).

Answer (score 1):

As Bogdan said, you have to check the query plan to understand why your query is so long.
And I would say that you have to do that **before** creating any index "au petit bonheur" (I am not saying that the index suggested by Bogdan is wrong, but without knowing the data ... it's a guess :) .
There is a comment in your code that shows that you tried a temp table instead of a table variable (the --drop table #rectodate).
For performance reasons, I would stay with a temp table because you can add index to a temp table not to a table variable (and by the way table variables are created in tempdb too).